# I can't get images from a repeater using Advanced Custom Fields WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, image, advanced-custom-fields

I have attached the screenshot of my repeater and image Advance Custom Fields.

[image: Image returning a url in a repeater]

I have uploaded threeimages for the repeater images block.

And Now, I am able to get those boats but cant view it on the screen. I open up my inspect element and I see the while loop executing and showing all three boats code.

My Code:

```
        <?php 
/* 
Template Name: boatProduct 
*/ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

            <?php if( have_rows('boat_product_slider') ): while ( have_rows('boat_product_slider') ) : the_row(); ?>
            <div class="product_boat" style="background: url('<?php the_sub_field('slider_image'); ?>'); background-size: cover;">

            </div>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

        </div>

        <div id="charter" class="brokerage" style="background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.95), rgba(255,255,255,0.95)), url('<?php the_field('agys_icon'); ?>') no-repeat center 48%; background-size: 80%;  background-attachment: fixed;">


        <h3 style="margin-top:40px;">Specification</h3>
        <p align="justify"><?php the_field('content'); ?></p>
    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: what do you mean _I cant get to execute the first if condition_ ? Is it print out not found? or what?

Comment: Yes, what I mean by it is, I need to get if loop running than an else loop. Even though I have 2 images for the repeater I endup with no rows else block executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a slight change you need to make to your code, replacing `the_sub_field()` with `get_sub_field()`.

From the [`get_sub_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_sub_field/) documentation:

> This function will **return** a sub field value from a repeater field or flexible content field loop. This function is used within a `have_rows()` loop.

The [`the_sub_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_sub_field/) function will print the results. This will not work for you as you've set your `slider_image` to return the "Image Object".

From the documentation:

> This function will display a sub field value from a repeater field or flexible content field loop. This function is used within a `have_rows()` loop.
>
> This function is the same as `echo get_sub_field('name');`.

---

#### Edit: "The Loop"

You have two options on how to handle the WordPress loop:

#### Option 1

The ACF functions need to be used inside the [WordPress loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). For example (using `page.php` from the default TwentySixteen WordPress theme:

```
<?php
// Start the loop.
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();


    // ACF functions should be added here, inside "the Loop"


    // Include the page content template.
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
    if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
        comments_template();
    }

    // End of the loop.
endwhile;
?>
```

#### Option 2

Alternatively, you can add the `$post_id` parameter to [`have_rows()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/have_rows/) to specify which post/page that the ACF fields should come from:

> `$post_id`: Specific post ID where your value was entered. Defaults to current post ID (not required). This can also be options / taxonomies / users / etc

```
$post_id = 123; // This should be the ID of the post/page that contain the ACF fields
if( have_rows('boat_product_slider', $post_id) ):

    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('boat_product_slider', $post_id) ) : the_row();
        // ...
```

Comment: I dont mind getting the url really. Can you show me how can I get it to working, I have replaced the_sub_field() to get_sub_field(). but still I get the the else loop printed rather than executing the if loop.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the entire code that I have. Also, its a custom template.

Comment: Okay. I will try doing as you suggested

Comment: I couldnt get it to work. And now, I am trying something else. could you please tell me how can I get all the images url link in my custom page template? I have a repeater called slider and I have an image in a repeater and I have selected this time a image url as a return. All I need is list of images url in an array. I have figured out everything else. I will update my code now. please have a look. I am new to acf and wordpress to be honest. So I am not aware of the functions or methods that I could use.